# How to configure DNN portals to use same username and password

Tags: authentication, dotnetnuke, portal, dotnetnuke-5

just we have small problem with DNN portals. we have two DNN websites one DNN 5 and 7.5 we need to make users of DNN5 able to login to DNN7 with same username and password.can we do this scenario in DNN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't something that is easy to do with DNN, you'll need to setup a database task/service that keeps the users, user portals, roles, and ASPNET_ tables in sync across the two installs.

That, or you will need to write a custom authentication provider for both DNN 5 and DNN 7 that use an different database to store user information.

Comment: would they need to use the same machine id?

Comment: If sync'ng the data across multiple databases, than yes, they would need to use the same machine keys in the web.config for encryption/decryption of the passwords

Comment: is their are module to do the sync between dnn5 and dnn7?

Comment: I don't know of one that will sync across multiple installs

Answer (score 0):

I think this module could do the job http://store.dnnsoftware.com/home/product-details/dnn-login-with-sso-12

But you might want to contact them to make sure it works for your case.